# .htaccess to redirect to a wp page

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, rewrite-rules

My custom .htaccess commands are above the WP ones. This is working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ wp-content/ahoj.txt [N]
</IfModule>
```

It shows the contents of my file ahoj.txt at the root of example.com

While this isn't working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ language/ [N]
</IfModule>
```

As language/ is not a real directory, but a permalink set by wp (wpml). How do I make the contents of `example.com/language` visible at `example.com` without changing the URL?

Comment: You need to do this in WordPress, not `.htaccess`. When you internally rewrite the request (in htaccess), WP still "sees" the URL that was requested (ie. the root), not the URL that is rewritten to (ie. `/language`). And you should be using the `L` flag, not `N`! (No need to repeat the `<IfModule>` and `RewriteEngine` directives.)

Comment: in WordPress means with `add_rewrite_rule()` ? I couldn't get that work either...